# Why are there more prime factors of the form $4k-1$ than of the form $4k+1$?

Tags: limits, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

The density of primes of the form $4k-1$ and $4k+1$ is equal although slight discrepancy exists in the exact numbers also known as Chebyshev bias. All odd prime factors of a number will be either of the form $4k-1$ or $4k+1$. If we take all natural numbers $n \le x$ and look at the prime factors of each of these numbers, the density of prime factors of $4k-1$ significantly higher than that of the form $4k+1$, i.e. the bias is much stronger than Chebyshev bias. Experimental data shows that the difference between their densities is a constant.

Let $a(n)$ = no. of distinct primes factors of $n$ which are of the form $4k-1$ and $b(n)$ = no. of distinct primes factors  of $n$ which are of the form $4k+1$.

Data at every checkpoint from $x = 10^6$ to $x = 10^9$ shows a consistent trend that

$$
\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n \le x} [a(n) - b(n)] \approx 0.83498
$$

At a more granular level, we consider only odd numbers then the above constant is $\approx 0.33498$ and if we consider only even numbers then it is $\approx 1.33498$.

**Question**: What is the source of this bias and is there a closed form of

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{x} \sum_{n \le x} [a(n) - b(n)]
$$

Comment: I don't quite understand the definition of $f$. For example, what is $f(10)$? The "number of prime factors of the form $4k-1$ in all natural numbers ≤ 10". So do I look at $3,6,7,9$ which each have a prime factor of that form? And then do I count to $4$ as the result? Or to $5$ accounting for $3^2$ dividing $9$?

Comment: @alex.jordan I have clarified the definition further to make it more explainable. Here is an examples. $f(10)$ = no. of unique primes of the form $4k-1$ in $1$ + no. of unique primes of the form $4k-1$ in 2 + no. of unique primes of the form $4k-1$ in $3$ + $\cdots$ + no. of unique primes of the form $4k-1$ in $9$ + no. of unique primes of the form $4k-1$ in $10$ = $0 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 0 = 4$

Comment: Considering even the Chebyshev bias is unproved (unless we assume strong forms of the Reimann hypothesis), I think it unlikely that you’ll find the source of this discrepancy.

Comment: I don't intend to criticize Jacob or their comment, but I think it's worth pointing out that Jacob's guess here, though plausible-seeming, was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a complete and rigorous answer, but I think it is a good start to an explanation.

Up to $x$, you can squeeze in more numbers with $3$ as a factor than you can numbers with $5$ as a factor. Just from $3$ and $5$, you have a difference of something like $\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}=0.1\overline{3}$.

Trying to measure this, I believe what you have is:

$$f(x)=\left\lfloor\frac{x}{3}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{x}{7}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{x}{11}\right\rfloor+\cdots$$
$$g(x)=\left\lfloor\frac{x}{5}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{x}{13}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{x}{17}\right\rfloor+\cdots$$

So $\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{x}$ is something like:

$$\frac13-\frac15+\frac17+\frac1{11}-\frac1{13}-\frac1{17}+\frac1{19}+\cdots$$

This is [converging to something](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+from+n%3D2+to+2000+of+%28-1%29%5E%28%28prime%28n%29%2B1%29%2F2%29%2Fprime%28n%29) that is suspiciously close your result ($0.3349\ldots$) when only examining odd numbers less than $x$.

Note that your result for looking among even numbers ($1.3349\ldots$) is this number plus $1$. And then the original of your three results ($0.8349\ldots$) is the average of those two numbers. Of course averaging the first two numbers would make sense, but why is the even count 1 more than the odd count?

Are factors of $2$ being properly omitted from your counts for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$? I notice that $\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+\cdots=1$, and if factors of $2$ (with repetition) were included in the count for $f(x)$, it would account for that additional $1$. But I am just speculating.

Comment: This argument can be made rigorous, and the limit does indeed equal $\displaystyle\sum_{p\ge 3}\dfrac{(-1)^{(p+1)/2}}p \approx 0.3349$ (where the sum is over all odd primes). I suspect that the OP is counting the prime $2$ along with the primes of the form $4k-1$; that would explain the offsets of $\frac12$ and $1$.

Comment: @GregMartin It looks like I was having similar thoughts about $2$ and adding that to this answer at the same time as your comment.

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, you are right, factors of $2$ were being counted. Once we eliminate them, the limit agrees with the above closed form.

Comment: Many years ago (so I don't have it at mind correctly) I was hinted to "prime-race", which (if I remember correctly) compared the same types of primes. Perhaps googling for this keyword?

Comment: "Prime races" is indeed a topic of number theory research. I'll note though that in this particular problem, we're weighting the primes being counted by $\frac1p$ (as we see in the answer), and that turns out to be much simpler to analyze than the general prime-race phenomena where we literally count primes (i.e., weight them by $1$ instead of $\frac1p$).